# crontab job does not work as expected, but called manually works

Tags: python, bash, unix, cron

I am having a problem on my crontab job. I'm a calling a bash script that launches two python scripts (both do not terminate) that interact with one application.

```
@reboot /bin/sh /home/user/path/to/bash_script/foo.sh
```

On my foo.sh file I call the two python scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin/ &
python /home/user/path/to/python_script1/bar.py & 
python /home/user/path/to/python_script2/baz.py &
```

On every boot I can check that bar and baz supposably are running by performing

```
ps aux | grep python
```

But when I open the application, **the second python script(baz) is not working as expected**.

If I call manually foo.sh, **everything on the application works as expected**.

I have tried several approaches like calling the python scripts on the crontab but the result has been the same.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
cd /usr/bin/ &
```

you're sending the command to the background i.e. spawning a subshell and running `cd` in that, with the original shell's current working directory remaining as-is.

Assuming you've something in your Python scripts that depend on the relative path of executables in `/use/bin/`, drop the `&`:

```
cd /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks heemayl! I tried your suggestion but it didn't work out. My second script does not launch...

`#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin/
python /home/user/path/to/python_script1/bar.py &
python /home/user/path/to/python_script2/baz.py &`

Comment: @FAM I think that's a different problem. You should look at the errors instead. The original issue should be solved by removing the subshell invocation like I mentioned in my answer.